# firebase return onSnapshot promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, callback, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase/firestore and I'm looking a way to return promise of snapshot.

```
onlineUsers(){
     // i want to return onSnapshot
    return this.status_database_ref.where('state','==','online').onSnapshot();
}
```

in other file I did

```
  componentDidMount(){
    // this.unsubscribe = this.ref.where('state','==','online').onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate) 
    firebaseService.onlineUsers().then(e=>{
        console.log(e)
    })
}
```

I get the errors

> Error: Query.onSnapshot failed: Called with invalid arguments.
>
> TypeError: _firebaseService2.default.unsubscribe is not a function

if i do this way

```
onlineUsers(){
   return  this.status_database_ref.where('state','==','online').onSnapshot((querySnapshot)=>{
        return querySnapshot
    }) 
}
```

I get

```
TypeError: _firebaseService2.default.onlineUsers(...).then is not a function
```

in addition,
when I do this way

```
   this.unsubscribe = firebaseService.onlineUsers().then((querySnapshot)=>{
        console.log(querySnapshot.size)
        this.setState({count:querySnapshot.size})
    })
```

// other file

```
 onlineUsers(callback) {
    return this.status_database_ref.where('state', '==', 'online').get()
}
```

it not listen to change into firebase, means if I change in firebase it's not update or change the size..

---- firestore function ---
I tried to make firestore function that trigger each time the UserStatus node updated but this take some seconds and it slow for me.

```
module.exports.onUserStatusChanged = functions.database
.ref('/UserStatus/{uid}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    // Get the data written to Realtime Database
    const eventStatus = change.after.val();

    // Then use other event data to create a reference to the
    // corresponding Firestore document.
    const userStatusFirestoreRef = firestore.doc(`UserStatus/${context.params.uid}`);


    // It is likely that the Realtime Database change that triggered
    // this event has already been overwritten by a fast change in
    // online / offline status, so we'll re-read the current data
    // and compare the timestamps.
    return change.after.ref.once("value").then((statusSnapshot) => {
        return statusSnapshot.val();
    }).then((status) => {
        console.log(status, eventStatus);
        // If the current timestamp for this data is newer than
        // the data that triggered this event, we exit this function.
        if (status.last_changed > eventStatus.last_changed) return status;

        // Otherwise, we convert the last_changed field to a Date
        eventStatus.last_changed = new Date(eventStatus.last_changed);

        // ... and write it to Firestore.
        //return userStatusFirestoreRef.set(eventStatus);
        return userStatusFirestoreRef.update(eventStatus);
    });
});
```

function to calculate and update count of online users

```
module.exports.countOnlineUsers = functions.firestore.document('/UserStatus/{uid}').onWrite((change, context) => {

    const userOnlineCounterRef = firestore.doc('Counters/onlineUsersCounter');

    const docRef = firestore.collection('UserStatus').where('state', '==', 'online').get().then(e => {
        let count = e.size;
        return userOnlineCounterRef.update({ count })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Promise` in JavaScript can resolve (or reject) exactly once. A `onSnapshot` on the other hand can give results multiple times. That's why `onSnapshot` doesn't return a promise.

In your current code, you're left with a dangling listener to `status_database_ref`. Since you don't do anything with the data, it is wasteful to keep listening for it.

Instead of using `onSnapshot`, [use `get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection):

```
onlineUsers(callback){
    this.status_database_ref.where('state','==','online').get((querySnapshot)=>{
        callback(querySnapshot.size)
    }) 
}
```

Or in your original approach:

```
onlineUsers(){
    return this.status_database_ref.where('state','==','online').get();
}
```

Comment: frank, I edited my post. I did your way and it not listen to change in firestore. if I change manually the state  to offline, the size I get, not change and I do see it invoke again the query

Comment: Neither the code in your question, nor in your answer, listens for changes. Both `onSnapshot` and `get()` will immediately return the current documents matching the query. The code I've given in my answer now will show you which users are currently online. It's unclear to me at this point what your code is trying to accomplish (it starting to feel like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: I want to listen to 'status' collection. if user signup to firebase it change his status with uid to' online', when he close app it change to 'offline'. I want to get the current size of online users. if user in app and other user is close app so it should show the real and update count

Comment: hey frank, do you any solution?

Comment: I honestly still don't understand what the goal is here. Or maybe it's that I can't figure out how to translate it into code. How is what your (or my) query now returns different from what you need?

Comment: your query works good, BUT when when I'm on the app and someone new is changed to 'online' or 'offline' the counter is not changed. the counter not calculate again, it not listen to changes!  in addition, I edited my post and did it with firestore function but it take like 3-5 seconds to update it and it slow for me

Answer (score 3):

I know it's too late but here is my solution using TypeScript & Javascript.

> TYPESCRIPT

```
const _db=firebase.firestore;
const _collectionName="users";

    onDocumentChange = (
    document: string,
    callbackSuccess: (currentData: firebase.firestore.DocumentData, source?: string | 'Local' | 'Server') => void,
    callbackError?: (e: Error) => void,
    callbackCompletion?: () => void
) => {
    this._db.collection(this._collectionName).doc(document).onSnapshot(
        {
            // Listen for document metadata changes
            includeMetadataChanges: true
        },
        (doc) => {
            const source = doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites ? 'Local' : 'Server';
            callbackSuccess(doc.data(), source);
        },
        (error) => callbackError(error),
        () => callbackCompletion()
    );
};
```

> JAVASCRIPT (ES5)

```
var _this = this;
onDocumentChange = function (document, callbackSuccess, callbackError, callbackCompletion) {
    _this._db.collection(_this._collectionName).doc(document).onSnapshot({
        // Listen for document metadata changes
        includeMetadataChanges: true
    }, function (doc) {
        var source = doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites ? 'Local' : 'Server';
        callbackSuccess(doc.data(), source);
    }, function (error) { return callbackError(error); }, function () { return callbackCompletion(); });
};
```

Comment: I wish I could provide 2 upvotes: one for the correct solution and one for giving the solution in TypeScript!

Comment: Thanks! @Patrick - just accept (Click the tick button) the answer if this is helpful for you.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to do that

```
onlineUsers(callback){
   return  this.status_database_ref.where('state','==','online').onSnapshot((querySnapshot)=>{
        callback(querySnapshot.size)
    }) 
}

componentDidMount(){

    this.unsubscribe = firebaseService.onlineUsers(this.onUpdateOnlineUsers);
    console.log(this.unsubscribe)
}
onUpdateOnlineUsers(count){
    this.setState({count})
}
componentWillUnmount(){
    this.unsubscribe();

}
```