# Firestore onSnapshot value that I console log (array) is different from the one I return (function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, es6-promise

I've been stuck on this for quite a while now and have no idea what's going on.

I'm running the following function:

```js
const getEmployees = async () => {
    const query = await db.collection('employees')
    const employees = query.onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
        const employeeArr = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            employeeArr.push(doc.data());
        });

        console.log(1, employeeArr)
        return employeeArr;
    })
    console.log(2, employees)
    return employees
}
```

the console.log(employeeArr) shows me exactly what I want to retrieve: an array with objects that consist of employee details (name, birhtday). However when I return this array and console.log(employees) after it logs the following:

```js
ƒ () {
      i.Xl(), r.os.ds(function () {
        return Rr(r.B_, o);
      });
    }
```

This (2) is also logged before the array (1).

I've been following the documentation on firestore and so far so good but I can't wrap my head around this. If I call getEmployees() and store the value it returns it also shows the unction. Anyone have any idea why and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876800/firebase-return-onsnapshot-promise) in more details, but here's the key: `onSnapshot` doesn't return a useful value, instead it expects a callback function which it'll supply data into. What it does return is a 'unsubscribe' function you're expected to call whenever you're done with snapshot.

Comment: @raina77ow No, onSnapshot returns a crucially useful function that you use to unregister the listener that you should call when you're done with it.

Comment: @DougStevenson The point is that it's not important, but that's not a value OP expects to work with.

Comment: @raina77ow Thanks! That makes a lot of sense :D I will use a callback to grab the data I need!

Answer (score 1):

You're saving inside the employees variable the result of query.onSnapshot().
Also with onSnapshot() the callback is called everytime there is a data update in the collection, wathing at your code I think that you simply want to get data once and to do so you just need to:

```
const employees = await query.get();
```

Reference here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Thanks for the response! I used get() before but I specifically want to do this with onSnapshot since it's important to be able to add new employees and see them updated in real time. Any way this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix the use of promises with realtime database listeners.  They're not compatible.  Functions that return a promise (like any async function) are meant to return a single result asynchronously.  **`onSnapshot` does not return a promise.**  Instead, it invokes the provided callback whenever the results of the query change.

If you want realtime results, you're going to have to deal with the snapshot listeners correctly.  `onSnapshot` returns a function that you call to remove the listener when you're done with it.  You can see an example in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener):

```
var unsubscribe = db.collection("cities")
    .onSnapshot(function (){
      // Respond to data
      // ...
    });

// Later ...

// Stop listening to changes
unsubscribe();
```

Failing to remove this listener when you're done means that you will leak the listener, and you will be charged for its reads over time.  That's bad.

Comment: Thank you for your response! That makes alot of sense,  I'll use a callback to grab the data I need :)

Answer (score 0):

use getDocs function from firebase

```
    const getEmployees = async () => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "employees"));
     const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
     const employeeArr = [];
     querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      employeeArr.push(doc.data());
     })
     console.log(employeeArr)
     return employeeArr
   }
```